# how can I add data to posts that can be retrieved by WP Rest API

Tags: posts

I used [Custom Field Suite](http://customfieldsuite.com/) to add fields to all WordPress posts, but the field data does not show when I retrieve post data through the [WP Rest API](http://wp-api.org/) using [/posts](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts) on a stand alone site.

Is there a way to add the CFS data so that it is retrieved by wp-json/posts REST calls?  It feels like I just need to put a CFS()->get call in the right place.  Or just a basic way to add data to posts so they are retrievable in REST calls?

I've added github issues for [CFS](https://github.com/mgibbs189/custom-field-suite/issues/266) and [WP-API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1201), and a general [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110998/how-can-i-add-data-to-posts-in-wordpress-that-can-be-retrieved-by-wp-rest-api) but any help or direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I think WP-API sends back metadata, check out http://wp-api.org/#entities_metadata

Answer (score 1):

The WP API has hooks, like

```
rest_prepare_page
```

to enhance the endpoints. For each post type give it different hooks the follow code example add the tags to post and page and illustrate, how it works.

```
 /** 
   * Add properties to posts and pages endpoints.
   */function wp_api_theming_posts_properties( $response ) {    

    // Set author's name.   
    $author = get_userdata( $response->data['author'] );
    $response->data['author'] = array(      'id' => $author->ID,        'link' => get_author_posts_url( $author->ID ),      'name' => $author->data->display_name,  );  

     // Add post classes.
        $response->data['post_class'] = get_post_class( '', $response->data['id'] ); 

    // Add categories.  
   $categories = wp_api_theming_get_post_terms( $response->data['id'], 'category' );

    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) { 
        $response->data['categories'] = $categories;
    } 

    // Add tags.    $tags = wp_api_theming_get_post_terms( $response->data, 'post_tag' );

    if ( ! empty( $tags ) ) {   
        $response->data['tags'] = $tags;    }   return $response;
   }

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'wp_api_theming_posts_properties' );

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_page', 'wp_api_theming_posts_properties' );  

/** * Get a post's terms with archive links. */
function wp_api_theming_get_post_terms( $id = false, $taxonomy = 'category' ) {

   // We need an ID for this one.
  if ( ! $id ) {        
      return FALSE; 
  }     

  // Validate the taxonomy argument.      
  $valid_tax = apply_filters( 'wp_api_theming_valid_tax', array( 'category', 'post_tag' ) );

  $taxonomy = ( in_array( $taxonomy, $valid_tax ) ) ? $taxonomy : 'category';   
  // Fetch our terms.   
 $terms = wp_get_post_terms( absint( $id ), $taxonomy );    

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) ) {
       // Append a link property to each term.
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
               $link = get_term_link( $term );
               $term->link = $link;     
        }   
    }   

 return $terms;
}
```

Also see my small plugin to reduce the result of the API for different points. I think it also helpful to understand how you can change, enhance the result, the endpoints.
https://github.com/bueltge/WP-REST-API-Filter-Items